# I am unable to pass props from parent to child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Starting out with react, I have created an input field in the parent component, When the user submits the text, I am passing down the text to the child component and printing the text under the parent component.

Code of parent component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Validate from "./Validate";

function CommandEntry() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(value);
    return <Validate value={value} />;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        enter text:~
        <input
          type="text"
          autoFocus
          required
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CommandEntry;
```

Code of child component

```
import React from "react";

export default function Validate(props) {
  console.log("I am in child");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.value}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your returning a component from your handler ? 
Are you sure that is what you want to do or is that a typo ?

Comment: I want to return the input text value in h1 and print it below the input field

Comment: Posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a JSX element from a handler function. Handler functions are different and render functions are different. So here you can change this in your parent component in which child will be shown only when `submit` is `true`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Validate from "./Validate";

function CommandEntry() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [submit, setSubmitValue] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitValue(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        enter text:~
        <input
          type="text"
          autoFocus
          required
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
      {submit && <Validate value={value} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CommandEntry;
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to `render` the child inside `return` and the set the value in handler.

Like so:

```
function CommandEntry() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [submit, setSubmitValue] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValue(e.target.value); //setting the value on change

  };
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitValue(true); //setting the submit flag to true.
  };
  return (
    <div>
      value &&
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> // submit handler
        enter text:~
        <input
          type="text"
          autoFocus
          required
          onChange={handleChange} // change handler
        />
       {submit && 
        <Validate value={value} /> // rendering the child component 
       }
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But this is changing the value whenever there is a change in text, I want to display the input text only after the form is submitted